# Working with automatic download file if I dont have access on the database or website

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, windows, forms

I have a task that needs to automatically download a file once the user click the button “ok”. I don't have access on the database or source code on the website, just view site access only. I don't know where and how to create it for me to start working on it. I been trying to do it using windows form but I'm not sure if its possible since the application is in the website.

How I can start doing this automatic download without any access on the applications code?

Comment: Right click, view source on the webpage? You have (some of) it's source, maybe viewing the HTML will give you the link. Otherwise you need to do scraping.

Comment: Is the "ok" button in a local desktop app or remote web site?

Comment: Once I click the button the record on the website will export to excel. The "Ok/Download All" button is in windows form c#. I'm using web browser. I think I need to used crawler for this then bypass all the page. But it's still confusing. Thanks for all your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `System.Net.WebClient` to download a file from the web.
However you should find a pattern in the file uri.

Here is a sample:

```
var FileDownload = "http://addressforthefile.pdf";
var FileSaveLocation = @"C:\Downloads\myfile.pdf";

var WebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
WebClient.DownloadFile(FileDownload, FileSaveLocation);
```